# Exec format Error. cxbf.ko from kernel has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, kernel, rhel6

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

I was updating RHEL packages and ended with errors like:

```
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
```

From the log below(See below), I understand that a new `kernel` version was getting installed and that got all these errors. When I look for the file `cxbf.co` in the searched destinations, I find it empty with size 0KB. In the very end, the log also shows the installed Packages as empty:
`Installed:`

But when I do:

```
uname -r
```

I find:

```
2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
```

Where the log rather says that the same kernel was removed:

```
Removed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-642.3.1.el6  kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-642.3.1.el6 

  kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6 kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6
```

Also, would like to say, when I see my `lib/modules` folder. I see a huge number folders (around 80 overall) named as:

```
2.6.9-67.EL
2.6.9-67.ELsmp
2.6.9-67.ELLargesmp
...etc
```

containing a folder `extra` which has a file: `cxbf.co`. (which is not empty).

Below is the update log:

```
Installing package(s) with command /usr/bin/yum -y install bind.x86_64 bind-chroot.x86_64 bind-libs.x86_64 bind-utils.x86_64 binutils.x86_64 ca-certificates.noarch dhclient.x86_64 dhcp-common.x86_64 kernel.x86_64 kernel-devel.x86_64 kernel-firmware.noarch kernel-headers.x86_64 ..
Loaded plugins: product-id, replace, search-disabled-repos, security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6 will be updated
---> Package bind.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 will be an update
---> Package bind-chroot.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6 will be updated
---> Package bind-chroot.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 will be an update
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6 will be updated
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 will be an update
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6 will be updated
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 will be an update
---> Package binutils.x86_64 0:2.20.51.0.2-5.44.el6 will be updated
---> Package binutils.x86_64 0:2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package ca-certificates.noarch 0:2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7 will be updated
---> Package ca-certificates.noarch 0:2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9 will be an update
---> Package dhclient.x86_64 12:4.1.1-51.P1.el6 will be updated
---> Package dhclient.x86_64 12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.1.1-51.P1.el6 will be updated
---> Package dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1 will be an update
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-696.10.2.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6 will be an update
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.2.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-642.3.1.el6 will be erased
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-642.3.1.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package    Arch   Version                   Repository                    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel     x86_64 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6       rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms  32 M
 kernel-devel
            x86_64 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6       rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms  11 M
Updating:
 bind       x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 4.0 M
 bind-chroot
            x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms  77 k
 bind-libs  x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 892 k
 bind-utils x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 189 k
 binutils   x86_64 2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1  rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 2.8 M
 ca-certificates
            noarch 2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9    rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 1.3 M
 dhclient   x86_64 12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1    rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 322 k
 dhcp-common
            x86_64 12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1    rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 144 k
 kernel-firmware
            noarch 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6       rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms  29 M
 kernel-headers
            x86_64 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6       rhui-rhel-6-server-rhui-rpms 4.5 M
Removing:
 kernel     x86_64 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6        @rhel-x86_64-server-6        131 M
 kernel-devel
            x86_64 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6        @rhel-x86_64-server-6         26 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade      10 Package(s)
Remove        2 Package(s)

Total download size: 86 M
Downloading Packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           8.4 MB/s |  86 MB     00:10     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                  1/24 
  Updating   : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                       2/24 
  Updating   : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.noarch                  3/24 
  Updating   : 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1.x86_64                   4/24 
  Updating   : 12:dhclient-4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1.x86_64                      5/24 
  Installing : kernel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64                           6/24 
  Updating   : 32:bind-chroot-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                7/24 
  Updating   : 32:bind-utils-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                 8/24 
  Updating   : ca-certificates-2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9.noarch               9/24 
  Updating   : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64                  10/24 
  Installing : kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64                    11/24 
  Updating   : binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1.x86_64                   12/24 
  Cleanup    : kernel-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64                           13/24 
warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/modules.order failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/modules.networking failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/modules.modesetting failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/modules.drm failed: No such file or directory
warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/modules.block failed: No such file or directory
  Cleanup    : 32:bind-chroot-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                   14/24 
  Cleanup    : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                          15/24 
  Cleanup    : 12:dhclient-4.1.1-51.P1.el6.x86_64                         16/24 
  Cleanup    : 32:bind-utils-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                    17/24 
  Cleanup    : 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-51.P1.el6.x86_64                      18/24 
  Cleanup    : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.noarch                 19/24 
  Cleanup    : kernel-devel-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64                     20/24 
  Cleanup    : ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch               21/24 
  Cleanup    : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64                  22/24 
  Cleanup    : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                     23/24 
  Cleanup    : binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.44.el6.x86_64                       24/24 
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.0.76-0.11-xen/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.0.76-0.11-xen/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.0.76-0.11-default/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.0.76-0.11-default/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-xen/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-xen/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-trace/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-trace/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-default/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-default/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/2.6.39-400.209.1.el5uek/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/2.6.39-400.209.1.el5uek/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/2.6.39-400.17.1.el6uek.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/2.6.39-400.17.1.el6uek.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/2.6.39-300.26.1.el5uek/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/2.6.39-300.26.1.el5uek/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
ERROR: modinfo: could not open /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
FATAL: /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/extra/cxbf.ko: Exec format error
Warning: Module cxbf.ko from kernel  has no modversions, so it cannot be reused for kernel 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
  Verifying  : binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1.x86_64                    1/24 
  Verifying  : 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1.x86_64                   2/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64                           3/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64                     4/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-utils-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                 5/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64                   6/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-chroot-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                7/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                       8/24 
  Verifying  : ca-certificates-2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9.noarch               9/24 
  Verifying  : 12:dhclient-4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1.x86_64                     10/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4.x86_64                 11/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.noarch                 12/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-utils-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                    13/24 
  Verifying  : 12:dhclient-4.1.1-51.P1.el6.x86_64                         14/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-chroot-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                   15/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                     16/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.noarch                 17/24 
  Verifying  : binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.44.el6.x86_64                       18/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64                  19/24 
  Verifying  : 32:bind-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.x86_64                          20/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64                           21/24 
  Verifying  : 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-51.P1.el6.x86_64                      22/24 
  Verifying  : ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch               23/24 
  Verifying  : kernel-devel-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64                     24/24 

Removed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-642.3.1.el6  kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-642.3.1.el6 

  kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6 kernel-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6

Updated:
  bind.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4                                         
  bind-chroot.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4                                  
  bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4                                    
  bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4                                   
  binutils.x86_64 0:2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1                                    
  ca-certificates.noarch 0:2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9                               
  dhclient.x86_64 12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1                                        
  dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6_9.1                                     
  kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6                                  
  kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.10.3.el6                                   

Complete!
Installed:
.. install complete.
```

Can you please help me figure out what has actually happened to my system here and how can I fix this.

Comment: Please show output for `rpm -qa | grep kernel` and `ls -l /boot/`.